# How to compare the HashMap data and the ArrayList data?

Tags: arraylist, groovy, hashmap, ready-api

I have the following HashMap data printing only the keySet(): -

```
[P001, P003, P005, P007, P004, P034, P093, P054, P006]
```

And the following ArrayList data as an output: -

```
[P001]
[P007]
[P034]
[P054]
```

This is how it is getting printed for both of them. I want to compare the array list data with the hash map data one by one. So, that the value [P001] should present inside HashMap.

Here is the part of code I have tried:-

```
def count = inputJSON.hotelCode.size() // Where "hotelCode" is particular node in inputJSON

Map<String,List> responseMap = new HashMap<String, List>()
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    Map jsonResult = (Map) inputJSON
    List hotelC = jsonResult.get("hotelCode")
    String id = hotelC[i].get("id")
    responseMap.put(id, hotelC[i])
}

String hotelCFromInputSheet = P001#P007#P034#P054
String [] arr  = roomProduct.split("#")
for(String a : arr) {
    ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
    list.addAll(a)

    log.info list
    log.info responseMap.keySet()

    if(responseMap.keySet().contains(list)) {
        log.info "Room Product present in the node"
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the first set a hash map? There are no key-value pairs there...

Comment: I am printing only the key, based on this only I want to compare it.

Comment: Then how to print the values() of the keys which are present inside the inputJSON node. That means I want to print the values() for [P001] [P007] [P034] [P054]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `containsAll` method of `Set`, which takes a collection:

```
if(responseMap.keySet().containsAll(list)) {
```

Not sure your code compiles, but it could at least be simplified:

```
String hotelCFromInputSheet = 'P001#P007#P034#P054'
ArrayList <String> list  = Arrays.asList(roomProduct.split("#"))
boolean containsAll = responseMap.keySet().containsAll(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line you check if keySet contains **whole** list:

```
if (responseMap.keySet().contains(list)) {
    log.info "Room Product present in the node"
}
```

I think that your intention was to check if it contains the String that has been added in loop that is currently being processed:

```
if (responseMap.keySet().contains(a)) {
        log.info "Room Product present in the node"
}
```

Also, in this line: `list.addAll(a)` you are really adding one String so it can be replaced with `list.add(a)` to make your code a bit clearer.

**Edit**: If you want to print values present in the `ArrayList` of Strings associated with the specified key, you might want to try using loop like this:

```
if (responseMap.keySet().contains(a)) {
    List<String> strings = responseMap.get(a);
    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.println(s + ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: After this I want to print the values() of the keys which are present inside the inputJSON node. That means I want to print the values() for [P001]
[P007]
[P034]
[P054].

Comment: @Ashuans I edited my answer, you might want to have a look at it to check if it is what you were asking for.